# How to Import MySQL dump file with Red Hat 6

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a VM that I'll be installing mysql server on. I have a dump file that I need to import into mysql. The first line says this:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.20, for linux-glibc2.5 (x86_64)
```

The file already has databases and tables, along with the structure and data.

```
 grep -i 'current database' db_dump.txt 
-- Current Database: `db1`
-- Current Database: `db2`
-- Current Database: `db3`

grep -i 'data for table' db_dump.txt 
-- Dumping data for table `TABLE1`
-- Dumping data for table `TABLE2`
-- Dumping data for table `TABLE3`
```

As you can see, its a .txt file and this is partly where my confusion is coming in. Much of what I have read is that in order to import a text file you must already have the database's and tables created. However they are already defined in the file. So that lead me to running a command such as this:

```
mysql -u <user> -p < filename.dump
```

But some of the documentation says you must have a .sql file in order to do this. So can I just rename my .txt file to .sql or just import as is? What would the command look like? I am really a noob when it comes to MySQL so any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the command? If so what did it output? It seems likely it will work, without seeing the entire file it would be impossible to tell if there are any issues with it. File extensions are less important in linux, in fact with the command you posted MySQL will never know what the filename was.

Comment: Have not tried yet. Just getting my ducks in a row.

Comment: See my answer, there actually was a little cleanup to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You command is correct. The extension of the filename is not important. It is what's inside that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! There is actually one thing that needs to change:

```
mysql -u<username> -p database_name < filename.dump
```

The database name should be the last part of the command and the username needs to go after `-u`, so if you are the root user you should type:

```
mysql -uroot -p database_name < filename.dump
```

Comment: Actually I did not need the database name. I ran it just like this - mysql -u root -p < filedump and it worked great. I suppose I could have used one of the default db's that were already included. But my file already had most of the defaults included so I chose to leave that out.

Comment: For future reference, if the file has a line that starts `CREATE DATABASE` then you won't need a database name (in fact you should probably not include one), if it doesn't, then you will.